# Rails: SASS not creating the CSS files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, sass

SASS is not creating the CSS files, but HAML is working just fine.

I ran the following command:

```
$: sass --watch scss:stylesheets
[true, ["scss", "stylesheets"]]
```

My **main.scss** file contains the following:

```
/* main.scss */

body {
    background: #000000;
}
```

The main.css file never gets generated. So I ran the following:

```
$: sass --update
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

What gives?

- Running Rails 3
- I've tried both **haml** and **haml-edge**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://github.com/nex3/haml/issues#issue/223). A fix will probably be released tonight or tomorrow night.

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to getting started with sass, thanks for letting me know about the upcoming fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your issue (I get a different error from you when I try to run it), but you're missing the brackets around your SCSS property list in the code you posted, so that code *shouldn't* parse correctly.